# MyFaces: how to show error messages in console log

Tags: jsf, myfaces

Running a JSF web application on MyFaces, if there's an error at the server side such as null pointer, what I get is a message that pops up in the browser but nothing is logged in the server console where more information on the error would be displayed. Is there a way to revert this? For example, this is a message that I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the error message, it's said that your project stage is development. that why the error don't get logged in the console. If you put your application in production mode it's should log normally in the console